# Adding input boxes dynamically using Javascript or AJAX

Tags: javascript

I have a column of input boxes and have a button for the last row to add more input boxes below the last input box. Is there a best way to do this ?

Comment: Are you using jQuery, or do you want to do this using just normal JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

You can go about something like this:

```
function addTextBox()
{
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  var txt = document.createElement('input');
  txt.type = 'text';
  txt.name = "my name";

  container.appendChild(txt);
}
```

In the above code, `container` is supposed to be your column id which contains text boxes.